# Not being able to allocate a pointer inside a void in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

When I try to use this and access the pointer, I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"....I dunno why

```
void insert(noAB *no, int chave){
        no=new noAB(chave);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. You'll find that the segmentation fault didn't occur on this line. There is a memory leak on this line, though.

Comment: @Alton000: "inside a `void`" is quite confusing. `void` is a type name. I think you meant inside a `void` **function**, i.e. inside a function which returns nothing. And that's directly the problem: you don't return the new pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `insert()` function must modify a pointer, then you need to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void insert(noAB **no, int chave){
    if (no != nullptr)
          *no=new noAB(chave);
}
```

However, as observed by MSalters in the comments, the C++ way is to rely on a reference:

```
void insert(noAB *&no, int chave){
          no=new noAB(chave);
}
```

Alternatively you can return the address of the object:

```
noAB* insert(int chave){
    return new noAB(chave);
}
```

Comment: The usual solution in C++ is `noAB*& no`, but if you ignore that you should instead check for `nullptr`.

Comment: Thank you. I've improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the pointer by value. Try this:

```
void insert(noAB **no, int chave){
        *no=new noAB(chave);
}
```